# Python Matplotlib - how to set values on y axis in barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python and I need to generate bar chart using pyplot and matplotlib. So far i tried like this (I have attached only the important code snippet):

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    finalDataset=[finalAverage,final4Average]
    N=len(finalDataset) 
    ind=np.arange(N)
    width=0.45
    rects1=plt.bar(ind,finalDataset,width,color='blue')
    plt.xticks(ind+width/2,("A","B"))
    plt.ylabel('y-axis')
    plt.xlabel('x-axis')
    plt.savefig("sample.png")
```

Output of this code is:
[image: output]

But my problem is I need output like this (Expected output) :
[image: expected output]

Comment: Can't you just divide your data by 1000000 before plotting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to keep the values of your `final4Average` the same, you could try something like this, to plot the dataset with a new array:

```
final4AverageModified = [x/1000000 for x in final4Average]
```

And you could edit your dataset to make it like this:

```
finalDatasetModified =[finalAverage, final4AverageModified]
```

And then, finally, make the plot-graphing call to make it like this:

```
rects1=plt.bar(ind, finalDatasetModified, width, color='blue')
```

This way, you can keep your original data in `final4Average` and keep the new data in `final4AverageModified`. This just divides your data before plotting.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome! If this has answered your question, please consider "accepting" this answer with the checkmark next to this answer!